# Create an Outlook event from a Office 365 Connector Card within a Teams chat

Tags: microsoft-teams, office365connectors

We're using inbound webhooks to send messages from an external service into a Microsoft Teams channel.  We're looking to leverage the Office 365 connector card (since we can't use adaptive cards with inbound webhooks...yet) to create messages.  When those messages arrive, one of the buttons we'd like to have on it would be one that allows the reader to at least start the process of creating an event on their Outlook calendar.

We've seen [how to create the Office 365 connector cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using) and note the ActionCard, HttpPost, and OpenUri options, but can't seem to see how this would all weave together to create an Outlook calendar item for the user.

Any recommendations on where to look?

Comment: You can use adaptive cards with internal web hooks, please see docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using#send-adaptive-cards-using-an-incoming-webhook)

For creating a calender event, best possible way would be using a deep link to  scheduling dialog. More info  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#linking-to-the-scheduling-dialog)

Comment: @Manish-MSFT thanks for helping out. We copied the JSON in the [link provided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-using#send-adaptive-cards-using-an-incoming-webhook) and received the following error via Postman: "Webhook message delivery failed with error: Microsoft Teams endpoint returned HTTP error 400 with ContextId...".  Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Unfortunately, adaptive  card json in the documentation is incorrect and we are fixing the same. You can create a adaptive card json in schema explorer and try and let us know here.

Comment: @Manish-MSFT thanks for the info. I can't seem to build an Adaptive Card from the schema explorer that works via Postman and an inbound webhook. Any chance you have an example?

Comment: {
   "type":"message",
   "attachments":[
      {
         "contentType":"application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
         "contentUrl":null,
         "content":{
            "$schema":"http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
            "type":"AdaptiveCard",
            "version":"1.2",
            "body":[
               {
                  
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "This is Adaptive Card",
            "weight": "bolder",
            "size": "medium"
          
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}